# How to create new row after 3 thumbnails exist in one row with bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to place 3 thumbnails in each row and I'm using "col-md-4". But if there are 4+ thumbnails a new row will be created and 3 thumbnails will be in that new row. How would I do this?

```js
 FB.api('/me/albums?fields=picture', 'get', {
   access_token: userToken
 }, function(response) {
   var data = response.data;
   for (var i = 0, l = response.data.length; i < l; i++) {
     var pictureUrl = data[i].picture.data.url;
     $("#albumPicturesModalBody").append("<div class=\"col-md-4\"><a class=\"thumbnail albumPicture\"><img src=\"" + pictureUrl + "\" alt=\"...\" class=\"img-rounded\"></a></div>");
   }

 });
```

```html
<div class="modal" id="albumPicturesModal" style="padding-top: 70px;" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Select An Album</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" style="max-height: 400px; min-height: 400px; overflow-y: scroll;">
        <div class="row" id="albumPicturesModalBody">

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is in response to your other question: "How to calculate number of bootstrap rows based on number of images"

```
 function howManyRows(totalImages) {
        var count = Math.round(totalImages / 3);
        return count;
    }
    console.log(howManyRows(50)); // output: 17
```

You could use something like that to figure out how many rows to create for your other function request here.